# mysql first record retrieval

Tags: mysql, sql

While very easy to do in Perl or PHP, I cannot figure how to use mysql only to extract the first unique occurence of a record.

For example, given the following table:

```
Name   Date         Time          Sale
John   2010-09-12   10:22:22      500
Bill   2010-08-12   09:22:37      2000
John   2010-09-13   10:22:22      500
Sue    2010-09-01   09:07:21      1000
Bill   2010-07-25   11:23:23      2000
Sue    2010-06-24   13:23:45      1000
```

I would like to extract the first record for each individual in asc time order.
After sorting the table is ascending time order, I need to extract the first unique record by name.

So the output would be :

```
Name   Date         Time          Sale
John   2010-09-12   10:22:22      500
Bill   2010-07-25   11:23:23      2000
Sue    2010-06-24   13:23:45      1000
```

Is this doable in an easy fashion with mySQL?

Comment: wouldn't `Sue    2010-09-01   09:07:21      1000` be the first row in your output, because it's the earliest time? or do you want to order by `date` *and* `time`? however, then it would be `Sue    2010-06-24   13:23:45      1000`, still not `John`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that something along the lines of

```
select name, date, time, sale from mytable order by date, time group by name;
```

will get you what you're looking for

Comment: It sounds right but it does not work. I tried it earlier. Also, group by name, must precede the order section for the syntax.
A single record is pulled out, and I think that it is the first one in the table.
Thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: you need to perform a groupwise max or groupwise min !!

Answer (score 0):

In databases, there really is no "first" or "last" record; think of each record as its own, non-positional entity in the table. The only positions they have are when you give them one, say, using `ORDER BY`.

This will give you what you want. It might not be efficient, but it works.

```
select Name, Date, Time, Sale from
    (select Name, Date, Time, Sale from MyTable
        order by Date asc, Time asc) MyTable_subquery_name
group by Name
```

Note: `MyTable_subquery_name` is just a dummy name for the subquery. MySQL will give the error `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias` without it.

If only `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` were communicative operations, then this wouldn't have to be a subquery.

Comment: This looks like it works. Note that the keyword "asc" should be added after date as well.
What is the "MyTable_subquery_name" denote?

Comment: @Sammy - The MyTable_subquery_name is just a name for the subquery. MySQL will give the error `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias` without it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform a groupwise max or groupwise min

see below or http://pastie.org/973117 for an example

```
 select
  u.user_id,
  u.username,
  latest.comment_id
 from
  users u
 left outer join
 (
  select
   max(comment_id) as comment_id,
   user_id
 from
  user_comment
 group by
  user_id
 ) latest on u.user_id = latest.user_id;
```